# Calculate the cardinal of $\{f:\Bbb{N}\to \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N}):n \notin f(n)\}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Calculate the cardinal of $A=\{f:\Bbb{N}\to \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N}):n \notin f(n)\}$.

Ok, so I'm having some trouble with this problem. I know that since $A\subset \{f:\Bbb{N}\to \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})\}$ and therefore, $\#A\leq \#\{f:\Bbb{N}\to \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})\}=\mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak{c}$.

But I am not being able to proceed. I've been thinking it for a while. Any hint?

I've already seen that $\#B=\{f:\Bbb{N}\to \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N}):n \in f(n)\}=\mathfrak{c}$, however I don't think this actually helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  consider functions from the odd numbers to the power set of the even numbers. This is a subset of what you are looking for.